# How to check a checkbox created with VB's DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn on Runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I wanted to check/tick a column created with DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn on runtime.

here's a snippet of my code;

```
Dim checkCol As DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn = New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkCol)
```

After I added this column, I wanted to check/tick some of these checkboxes on start up of the VB application.

How do I do that? Do I have to make use of some of the methods from Checkbox Class?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CheckBox` accepts two values: `True` (checked) or `False` (unchecked). You can set/get the values of any cell of you `DataGridView` at runtime by doing:

```
DataGridView1(0, 0).Value = True 'Checking the CheckBox in the first row/first column 
Dim isChecked As Boolean = DirectCast(DataGridView1(0, 2).Value, Boolean) 'Getting the check status of the third row/first column.
```