# How to see if a datagridviewcheckbox is checked or not

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I have created a datagridview with a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn. Initially I read in my data and set the value of the checkbox to true if the data is there and false if it is not. This works fine, but If I change the state of the checkbox to either checked or unchecked from what it was previously, I can't read this change. When I try to save the data it always shows, the checkbox's original state.

How can I re-read the checkbox's value after it has been clicked?

I tried the solution show here:
[How to check a checkbox created with VB's DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn on Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570802/how-to-check-a-checkbox-created-with-vbs-datagridviewcheckboxcolumn-on-runtime)

using: `DirectCast(DataGridView1(0, 2).Value, Boolean)`

but it does not work for me. I always get the original state of the checkbox when I look at it. If the box was originally checked and I uncheck it, this value will still show True.

Comment: Why the cowardly down vote with no comment? This is a legitimate problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at the wrong row (you are looking at the first row only with the index of 0).  You can use the DataGridView_CellEndEdit Event to find the value of the checkbox, like so...

```
If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then 'this is the columnIndex of your checkbox column
    If MyBindingSource.Current("CheckBoxColumnName") = true then
        'the column is checked, so do something
    End If
End If
```